# Question inadvertently kicked into limbo. What to do?

Tags: support, specific-question

I asked a C/C++ question yesterday which appeared to interest several users.  The consensus however was that the question was valid but should be migrated to Meta.  Unfortunately now, on Meta, the consensus seems to be that the question *may* be valid, but belongs on the main site.

Hardly anyone seems to think the question improper—most seem to think that the question rightly belongs *somewhere* around here—but the result of shuttling the question [back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271299/1275653) and [forth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25818910/1275653) between Meta and the main site is that the question is now closed (or on hold) *on both sites.*

Incidentally, I have only posted the question once.  No reposting has occurred, but only a migration, followed by a counter-migratory hold.

Since my question was not intended to simulate a soccer ball, kicked about by the site's software, what should I do?

(My opinion need not matter, but if it does, then it seems to me that the question *in question* would belong on the main site.  By the way, the question is not so important that admins should spend an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out how to revive it!  The question does not matter that much to me; and anyway, answerers answered the question to *my* satisfaction before the question got double-closed.  Still, the result is a bit odd, and is obviously unintended, so I thought that I should ask.)

**UPDATE**

Please accept my thanks if you have spent time on this matter in one way or another.  It grows clear that (a) there probably exists no straightforward solution and (b) the problem, though interesting, may arise too rarely for the site to bother about.  My original question was after all satisfactorily answered *before* it was closed, so I no longer wonder about that.  It is only unfortunate for answerers of the original question that they have lost the chance to earn further reputation points for their answers.

If you have made a comment you would now like to elevate to an *answer* to the present question, feel free to do so; but otherwise you have already answered both the original question and the present question about as well as they can be answered.  For my part, I ask no further response.

Comment: The question doesn't belong on either Stack Overflow or Meta. It **may** be on topic on Programmers; you are asking a meta question about programming here after all.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for what they consider on-topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Actually it's a perfectly fine question for SO: "Why should I avoid Undefined Behavior like the plague, even though I know what happens on my implementation?". I'm sure its perfectly answerable (it was answered to everyones satisfaction, after all), and it's practical enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Perhaps, but I think it is a *less controversial* fit on Programmers then. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, but we should be a bit avaricious and not send good questions elsewhere, just because they might be an even better fit there. I think there were such comments from the mods when last they observed an over-eagerness to migrate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: true enough. I *am* surprised people thought the question belonged on Meta.

Comment: If I understood it, the awkward point was that my question seemed to regard [a] how C and C++ programmers think (which admittedly tends to support @MartijnPieters' point regarding programmers.stackexchange.com) and [b] StackOverflow culture in light of [a].  Now that others have helped me to see the matter more clearly in retrospect, what I *meant* (or should have meant) to ask was [a] rather than [b].  It was the [b] that seems to have made users think of Meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I could reword the question to make further migration unlikely, then post the reworded question on programmers.stackexchange.com.  The answers already posted, either on Meta or on the main site, were pretty good, though, as were the comments.  One would not like to abandon the existing answers and comments, if one could avoid doing so.

Comment: @thb: I don't think posts, once migrated, can be migrated *again*, but I could be wrong on that. You can always invite the answerers to re-post their answer on the new post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I sure hope a mod can unlock, reopen, and then handle it like any new post... Anyway, it's only closed as off-topic on SO proper, so clarify and it might be re-opened. Perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure if there's a restriction to user initiated migrations, but mods can migrate a post multiple times.

Comment: @Yannis: check; so is [Undefined behavior, in principle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25818910) suitable for Programmers at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. It asks for an explanation of programming concepts (although C++ is more dark magic than programming), so it seems like a good question for us.

Comment: I am confused as to why anyone though it made sense on meta. It is arguable whether it makes sense on SO vs programmers, but meta?!

Comment: *"Question inadvertently kicked into limbo. What to do?"* - write shorter questions. The verbosity makes it hard to parse the problem statement and the question. Because its hard to parse, folks don't read it completely. Because its not read completely, folks don't completely understand it. For example, in this question: *"Incidentally, I have only posted the question once..."* - so what? How is that relevant to anything? It does not add anything to the problem statement. All it does is make someone wade through spurious text to find the question.

Comment: @neminem I was the first one to suggest migrating to Meta, and it was because I interpreted the question as [b] from thb's comment above. I think I made the reason clear in one of my followup comments.